# How to programmatically submit an EditText on Android?

Tags: java, android

I have an activity containing an `EditText` and a `ListView`. `EditText.TextChangedListener` has been implemented to populate the `ListView` from a database as the user enters text.

I would like to implement `ListView.OnItemClickListener` in such a way that it has the same effect as pressing submit on the soft keyboard: when the user selects one of the entries in the ListView, the soft keyboard disappears and the `EditText` loses focus.

```java
// MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText myEditText;
    ListView myListView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myEditText = findViewById(R.id.my_edit_text);
        myEditText.setOnTextChangedListener(
            (s, start, before, count) -> populateMyListView(s)
        );
    
        myListView = findViewById(R.id.my_list_view);    
        myListView.setOnItemClickListener(
            (parent, view, position, id) -> submitMyEditText()
        );
    }
}
```

My question is, how would you implement `submitMyEditText()`?

Comment: Can you share full code for this functionality then it will be more clear.

Comment: @UmeshYadav For which function would you like to see the code, for `populateMyListView()`? I am not sure where to start implementing `submitMyEditText()`

Comment: I need both function  code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. If you got some error then comment here.

```
public void submitMyEditText(View view,EditText myEditText){
      hideSoftKeyBoard(view.getContext(),myEditText);
      myEditText.clearFocus();
}
```

Make function this for hole project in common class.

```
public static void hideSoftKeyBoard(Context context,View view){
 InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This code works perfectly, except for the call to view.getText(). Excellent idea to update the text in response to the user selection, though, I will consider finding a way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

So actually in Android the EditText doesn't lose focus upon hiding the soft keyboard.  It maintains focus but no longer shows the keyboard.  Not that there's anything wrong with choosing to make it lose focus, but the behaviors won't match if you do.

To clear the focus, use editText.clearFocus().

To hide the keyboard, use

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```